# how to use "scikit-learn calibration" after fine-tuning lightgbm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm, calibration

I fine tuned LGBM and applied calibration, but have troubles applying calibration.

I have 1) train, 2) valid, 3) test data.

**I trained and fine-tuned LGBM using 1) train data and 2) valid data.
Then, I got a best parameter of LGBM.**

After then, I want to calibrate, in order to make my model's output can be directly interpreted as a confidence level. But I'm confused in using scikit-learn [CalibratedClassifierCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV).

**In my situation, should I use cv='prefit' or cv=5? Also, should I use train data or valid data fitting CalibratedClassifierCV?**

**1) uncalibrated_clf but after training**

```
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], verbose=True, early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

**2-1) Calibrated_clf**

```
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv='prefit', method='isotonic')
cal_clf.fit(X_valid, y_valid)
```

**2-2) Calibrated_clf**

```
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=5, method='isotonic')
cal_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**2-3) Calibrated_clf**

```
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=5, method='isotonic')
cal_clf.fit(X_valid, y_valid)
```

Which one is right? All is right, or only one or two is(are) right?

Below is code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import calibration_curve
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
import lightgbm as lgb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
n_samples = 10000
X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=3*n_samples, n_features=20, n_informative=2,
    n_classes=2, n_redundant=2, random_state=32)
#n_samples = N_SAMPLES//10

X_train, y_train = X[:n_samples], y[:n_samples]
X_valid, y_valid = X[n_samples:2*n_samples], y[n_samples:2*n_samples] 
X_test, y_test = X[2*n_samples:], y[2*n_samples:]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '--', color='gray')

# 1) Uncalibrated_clf but fine-tuned on training data
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], verbose=True, early_stopping_rounds=20)

y_prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
fraction_of_positives, mean_predicted_value = calibration_curve(y_test, y_prob, n_bins=10)

plt.plot(
    fraction_of_positives,
    mean_predicted_value,
    'o-', label='uncalibrated_clf')

# 2-1) Calibrated_clf
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv='prefit', method='isotonic')
cal_clf.fit(X_valid, y_valid)

y_prob1 = cal_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
fraction_of_positives1, mean_predicted_value1 = calibration_curve(y_test, y_prob1, n_bins=10)

plt.plot(
    fraction_of_positives1,
    mean_predicted_value1,
    'o-', label='calibrated_clf1')


# 2-2) Calibrated_clf
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=5, method='isotonic')
cal_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_prob2 = cal_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
fraction_of_positives2, mean_predicted_value2 = calibration_curve(y_test, y_prob2, n_bins=10)

plt.plot(
    fraction_of_positives2,
    mean_predicted_value2,
    'o-', label='calibrated_clf2')

plt.legend()

# 2-3) Calibrated_clf
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=5, method='isotonic')
cal_clf.fit(X_valid, y_valid)

y_prob3 = cal_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
fraction_of_positives3, mean_predicted_value3 = calibration_curve(y_test, y_prob3, n_bins=10)

plt.plot(
    fraction_of_positives2,
    mean_predicted_value2,
    'o-', label='calibrated_clf3')

plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about this is:

a) fit the model and calibrate on the hold out set

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, cv='prefit').fit(X_val, y_val)
y_pred = calibrated.predict(X_test)
```

(this is actually the meaning of prefit here: the model is already fitted now take a new relevant set and calibrate the output).

b) fit the model and calibrate with cross validation on the training set

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, cv=5).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_val = calibrated.predict(X_val)
```

As is usually the case the number of cross validations and the method (isotonic regression vs Platt scaling or sigmoid in scikit-learn's jargon) critically depends on your data and your setup. Therefore, I'd suggest to put those in a grid search and see what produces the best results.

Finally, a deeper dive can be found here:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/calibrated-classification-model-in-scikit-learn/